# OpenGL mesh + mirror transformation = wrong lighting

Tags: opengl, 3d, cad

Frequently, you need to add to the 3D graphics scene a mirrored copy of the same object, like a car door or the left version of the right shoe. When you do this with a mirror transformation on a display list containing a mesh of triangles (vertices, triangles, and normals) you get illumination problems.

We are able to detect a reflection inside a 4x4 transformation matrix but we don't know how to recycle the same display list (draw it with correct illumination) simply changing OpenGL status flags.

I'm thinking of `glFrontFace()`, `GL_NORMALIZE`, etc.

Do you think it is possible without building a new display list of the mirrored object? If yes, how?

Comment: while mirroring reverse the order of vertexes ... Display list? why not VBO/VAO IIRC the display lists usually have no or negative performance impact on newer cards (I mean newer than 10-15 years old...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your usage of "display lists" and `GL_NORMALIZE`, it sounds like you're using old school fixed-function OpenGL. You'll want to enable a feature that was called *two-sided lighting*:

```
glLightModeli(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL_TRUE);
```

As a side note, if you have backface culling enabled you'll also want to flip the culling direction when drawing the flipped geometry:

```
glFrontFace(GL_CW); // the default setting is GL_CCW
```

Good luck, and I hope you can modernize; shaders are great!

Comment: We resolved inverting the `glFrontFace` setting only.

Comment: @prideout What would your approach be if shaders could be used instead of using `glFrontFace()`?  My understanding is that mirroring vertices either in shaders or matrices, requires cull changing.

Comment: @MikeWeir yes the `glFrontFace` would be required even if you use shaders.  The part that's different is the `glLightModeli` call, which does not exist in the new world.